Simulate a mouse click on another windows in Mac
I am trying to simulate a mouse click event in the new "IPhone Mirroring" feature that mac has to offer, I can do it via code that needs to take control of my mouse (moves my mouse and performs the click) but I am looking for a way to do it without having to give control of my computer. since I would like to automate some tasks on my IPhone.
So far, I tried every single answer from StackOverFlow, nothing seems to help, here is my code.
import SwiftUI
import CoreGraphics
import AppKit

struct ContentView: View {
    func simulateMouseClick() {
        // Find target window
        guard let targetApp = NSWorkspace.shared.runningApplications
            .first(where: { $0.localizedName?.contains("iPhone Mirroring") == true }),
              let windowList = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(.optionOnScreenOnly, kCGNullWindowID) as? [[String: Any]],
              let targetWindow = windowList.first(where: { ($0[kCGWindowOwnerPID as String] as? pid_t) == targetApp.processIdentifier }),
              let bounds = targetWindow[kCGWindowBounds as String] as? [String: Any],
              let x = bounds["X"] as? CGFloat,
              let y = bounds["Y"] as? CGFloat,
              let width = bounds["Width"] as? CGFloat,
              let height = bounds["Height"] as? CGFloat,
              let windowNumber = targetWindow[kCGWindowNumber as String] as? Int else {
            return
        }
        
        // Move mouse and create click point
        let point = CGPoint(x: x + width/2, y: y + height/2)
        CGDisplayMoveCursorToPoint(CGMainDisplayID(), point)
        
        // Create click events
        guard let mouseDown = NSEvent.mouseEvent(
            with: .leftMouseDown,
            location: point,
            modifierFlags: [],
            timestamp: ProcessInfo.processInfo.systemUptime,
            windowNumber: windowNumber,
            context: nil,
            eventNumber: 0,
            clickCount: 1,
            pressure: 1.0
        )?.cgEvent,
        let mouseUp = NSEvent.mouseEvent(
            with: .leftMouseUp,
            location: point,
            modifierFlags: [],
            timestamp: ProcessInfo.processInfo.systemUptime,
            windowNumber: windowNumber,
            context: nil,
            eventNumber: 0,
            clickCount: 1,
            pressure: 1.0
        )?.cgEvent else {
            return
        }
        
        // Try to click twice
        mouseDown.post(tap: .cghidEventTap)
        usleep(100_000)
        mouseUp.post(tap: .cghidEventTap)
        usleep(200_000)
        mouseDown.post(tap: .cghidEventTap)
        usleep(100_000)
        mouseUp.post(tap: .cghidEventTap)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Click Target Window") { simulateMouseClick() }
    }
}


Is this a permission issue? What is the problem? No clicks? One click? Wrong location?

If you don't want to move the mouse then why do you call CGDisplayMoveCursorToPoint?

It was for testing, to see if my click was actually going to the place I wanted to @Willeke
It doesn't seem to be a permission issue, since I can click just fine. I thought about wrong location, thats why I added MoveCursorToPoint.

There is no clicks on the window. no permission issue.

I tried your code, it clicks, but at the wrong location. Try creating a CGEvent (y = 0 is top of the screen) instead of a NSEvent (y = 0 is bottom of the window).

I see. @Willeke maybe I am missing some settings? I turned off app sandbox already.  and gave it the permission for accessability.

I'll try that as well.

still no luck with CGEvent. I am not sure how you got it to work, did you try it with iPhone Mirroring app?

iPhone Mirroring is not available in my country, I used the Calculator.

Might be an issue with the iPhone mirroring application then... since some applications block key events from what I read on google.
